# Prevent mat-expansion-panel from being toggled by SPACE key

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have tried the below code, `onFilterKeyboard` is getting called also, but still SPACE key is working.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel-header (keydown)="onFilterKeyboard($event);">
  <mat-panel-title (keydown)="onFilterKeyboard($event);">
    <div (keydown)="onFilterKeyboard($event);">{{aFilter.name}}</div>
  </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

In JS:

```js
onFilterKeyboard(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: post the tried code

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this in the component's `constructor` or `ngOnInit` :

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) { // 32 is space bar key code
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

(keydown.Space)="onFilterKeyboard($event);" worked.
It will create a pseudo event.
For more about pseudo event refer https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/angular-pseudo-events-d4e7f89247ee

Comment: In my case I had a textbox in the panel title that would toggle the expansion every time you pressed space or enter. Fixed it by adding the following to the <input>: (keydown.Space)="$event.stopPropagation()"(keydown.Enter)="$event.stopPropagation()"

Comment: @SteveInCO You may add your solution as an answer so others can find it faster.

Comment: @SteveInCO it doesn't seem to work anymore with Angular 14